# issue with list.groupBy()

Tags: collections, groovy

I have a list as below

```
def qresultList = [
    [location: 'a', txs: 10],
    [location: 'b', txs: 20],
    [location: 'a', txs: 30]
]
```

I want to get distinct list of locations with sum of txs for same location.. so I am doing groupby on location like this:

```
def totalsByLocation1 = qresultList.groupBy{ it.location }.
    collectEntries{ key, vals -> [key, vals*.txs.sum()] }
```

The above code is inside SummaryUtilsService/getWorldSummary function
I am getting the following error

```
No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.collectEntries() is applicable for argument types: (summary.SummaryUtilsService$_getWorldSummary_closure3) values: [summary.SummaryUtilsService$_getWorldSummary_closure3@2750e6c9]
```

**Update**: the actual result from the query is

```
def qresultList =  [
        ['a', 10],
        ['b', 20],
        ['a', 30]
    ]
```

so Its a list of lists..

Comment: What issue are you having? All you asked is if the code was right...run it...do you get the results you expect?

Comment: I assume you're using an old version of Groovy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From earlier questions, I assume you're using Grails 1.3.7 or something

The pre-groovy 1.8.X way of doing this is:

```
def totalsByLocation1 = qresultList.groupBy{ it.location }.inject([:]) { map, val ->
  map << [ (val.key): val.value*.txs.sum() ]
}
```

#### Edit

If your input list is:

```
def qresultList =  [
  ['a', 10],
  ['b', 20],
  ['a', 30]
]
```

Then you will need something like:

```
qresultList.groupBy { it[ 0 ] }.collectEntries { k, v ->
  [ (k): v*.getAt( 1 ).sum() ]
}
```

Comment: ok...as you said that..I just found that my resultset doesnot have named attributes 'location' and txs... so thats what was causing error.. and so I can replace the '.location' and '.txs' with indexes [0] and [1] right and should still work?? Thanks for pointing that out..

Comment: getting this error:  No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.collectEntries() is applicable for argument types: (summary.SummaryUtilsService$_getResourceEventComparisonChart_closure8) values: [summary.SummaryUtilsService$_getResourceEventComparisonChart_closure8@2dc5c9ca]

Answer (score 1):

For a list of maps:

```
assert [[a:40], [b:20]] == qresultList.groupBy {it.location}.collect {[(it.key): it.value.sum{it.txs}]}
```

For a map:

```
def locationTransactionSums = [:]
qresultList.groupBy {it.location}.each {
    locationTransactionSums.(it.key) = it.value.sum{it.txs}
}
assert [a:40, b:20] == locationTransactionSums
```

Comment: Nice, but that's a list of maps, not a map `[ a:40, b:20 ]`

Comment: Didn't realize that was what they wanted... Updating my post.  I need to learn how to utilize .inject() though.